# Makefile -L command

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

If I have this line in the make file:\

```
libpqxx_Libs = -L/share/home/cb -lpqxx-2.6.9 -lpq
```

Does this indicate the compiler to use the lpqxx-2.6.9.so shared object file or does this indciate the compiler to use all the .so in the foler lpqxx-2.6.9? Or is this something else altogether?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-L` in this context is an argument *to the linker*, that adds the specified directory to the list of directories that the linker will *search* for necessary libraries, e.g. libraries that you've specified using `-l`.

It isn't a makefile command, even though it's usually seen in makefiles for C projects.

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` is actually not a `makefile` command (as you state it in the title of your question).

What actually happens in this line is an assignment of a value to the variable `libpqxx_Libs` -- nothing more and nothing less. You will have to search in your `makefile` where that variable is used via `$(libpqxx_Libs)` or `${libpqxx_Libs}`. That is most likely as a argument in a link command, or a compile command that includes linking.

In that context, the meaning of `-L` and `-l` can be found in, for example, the [gcc man pages](http://www-hep2.fzu.cz/computing/htmldoc/gcc_hp.html), which state that

```
-llibrary
   Use the library named library when linking.

   The linker searches a standard list of directories  for  the  li-
   brary, which is actually a file named `liblibrary.a'.  The linker
   then uses this file as if it  had  been  specified  precisely  by
   name.

   The directories searched include several standard  system  direc-
   tories plus any that you specify with `-L'.
```